# Unable to get data from assets using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created application in stackblitz tool.

It's not getting data from `assets/data/architecture.json`.

But From url it's loading fine.  In `app.component.ts` file i have commented the line`(//  apiUrl2 = '/assets/data/architecture.json'; )`.

Please tell me where i did mistake.

Below is my stackblitz code URL. [Stackblitz Code URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-current)

Comment: Need a clarification....Do you want to load '..assets/data/architecture.json' as a config(Loaded by default during app loading)  , or as a web service (Can be called anytime, any place from any piece of code)?

Comment: i want lo load the json while the loading of the application in ngOnInit()

Comment: Check the answer I gave.

Comment: Sure, will tell u soon

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: See if helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176684/how-to-change-urls-automatically-in-services-after-changing-url-it-should-affec/54178616#54178616

Answer (score 0):

The request you are making to **/assets/data/architecture.json** will not return anything because you need a server running on localhost that will take care of your static files and when requested will return them. I suggest you look at this guide -> [THIS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli)
If you want to access the json without making a web request you can import it and require in your app.

```
declare function require(url: string);
const data= require('../assets/data/architecture.json');
```

Data will store the content of your json.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to load the '/assets/data/architecture.json' on app loading time, I`ll suggest to go with App_Initializer.

Create an ArchitecturePropertyLoaderService file, which will be used for initialization at App Loading time:

```
   import {ConfigProperties} from '../_model/config.property';
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Http} from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class ArchitecturePropertyLoaderService {

      stationUrl: string;
      // ArchitectureProperties must be a map of your /assets/data/architecture.json //
      confProp: ArchitectureProperties;
      constructor(private http: Http) {
      }

      getConfFile() {
        return this.http.get('assets/data/architecture.json')
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.confProp = data.json();
            // Your Code //
          }, error =>{
            console.log(error);
          }
          );
      }
//Can Access this from your code anywhere, just call this method //
  getConfigPropData(): ArchitectureProperties {
    return this.confProp;
  }
    }
```

In your AppModule, add a class as below:

```
export function startupServiceFactory(startupService: ArchitecturePropertyLoaderService ): Function {
    return () => startupService.getConfFile();
}
```

Now, in your provider section, use this:

```
providers: [
       {
            // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
            deps: [ArchitecturePropertyLoaderService],
            multi: true
        }],
```