# How to change URLs automatically in services, after changing URL it should affect to all components without saving/ building/running in angular6

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material, angular6

We are hosting a new application with angular 6 and we have many servers with diff URLs, i want to change them automatically(like .property file in java). after searching in google i got some answers like changing paths in environment.ts file, so it will affect to all components. but its not exactly my requirements, means if i change URL in environment.ts file, we should save the file and we need to compile it once again. So exactly this is the problem i am facing, i don't want to save / compile the file.

Please help me in this situation.

service.ts file.

```
emplLoginCheckUrl = this.baseUrl+"/checkValidUser";
```

i tried to change base url from environment.ts file, its working correctly but after saving the file, i dont want want save file it should change automatically.

.service.ts file.

```
 emplLoginCheckUrl = this.baseUrl+"/checkValidUser";

       validateUserDetails(employeeDetails): Observable<any> {
            console.log(this.baseUrl);
            return this._httpClinet.post(this.emplLoginCheckUrl, employeeDetails);
        }
```

environment.ts file.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: "http://rest/somerestservice"
};
```

Expected:

URLs should change automatically without saving/running/compiling/building again and again, because only one time I can do saving/running/compiling/building while hosting. after hosting if I want to change URLs I can't go there, change the path and cant compile it once again.

Comment: please check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233032/how-to-change-one-server-url-to-another-server-url-if-the-server-is-down-in-ang/54250834?noredirect=1#comment95327177_54250834

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the endpoint in as a query parameter when accessing the application for the first time like this:

```
http://localhost/yourapplication?baseUrl=http://rest/somerestservice
```

and then read this query parameter value in your app.component.ts and set it to the `baseUrl` environment variable.

Beware even though this would work, I don't know if this would be the most elegant way to achieve this.

Update: As OP requested code

Demo: https://angular-sku9xx.stackblitz.io/?baseUrl=http://rest/somerestservice

Code for the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sku9xx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Can u share the code, i am bit confused did not get it properly.

Comment: Updated answer with a demo.

Comment: Thx @  Awad Maharoof your solution is not working here, the same code is working in your case. i dont know where i am lagging.

Comment: @ Awad Maharoof its automatically detecting changes in your case, but in my case its not, can you help me where i am lagging, i tried the same code which you used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common scenario for the Angular application. 
That is, you don't want to build and compile again the code on the server, if you want to change backend api url. Following is the approach that i use with my Angular projects.

**Approach :**

1. Create a `config.json` file in the  `assets` folder, as assets folder is present on the server.

```
{  // ---------- config.json---------
  "serviceUrl": "http://172.168.1.190:1393/"
}
```

2. Create a variable `serviceUrl` in your `constants` file, as you will have a constant file for your angular application. Assign this variable `empty` value as this variable will keep the updated service url later.

```
export class AppConstants { 

  public static xhr = {
        url: {
                serviceUrl: ''  // <===== empty value
             }
       }
}
```

3. Implement `APP_INITIALIZER` to read the `config.json` file at the application start up. And read the value of `serviceUrl` from `config.json` and assign this value to the same variable present in the `constants` file.

```
   {   // in app.module.ts providers
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: ConfigurationServiceFactory,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true
    }
---------------------------------------------------
// ConfigurationServiceFactory which is used at App initialization
export function ConfigurationServiceFactory(configService: ConfigService) {
return () => configService.load();
};
---------------------------------------------------
// this method is called at application start up
// and config.json file is read here, and the service url from
// constant file is replaced by the value provided in the assets's config.json
load() {
const configUrl = '~/../assets/config.json';
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.http.get(configUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then((config: any) => {
            this.config = config;
            console.log('Configurationd fetched  : ', this.config);
            //----- variable is updated now with new value from the file -------
            AppConstants.xhr.url.serviceUrl = this.config.serviceUrl;
            resolve(true);
        })
        .catch( (err) => console.log(err));
    });
}
```

4. For every `HTTP` call, use the `constants` file's `serviceUrl` as the base url.

   **`this.http.get('${AppConstants.xhr.url.serviceUrl}api/roles/list')`**
5. As changing variable value in `assets` folder `config.json` will be fetched at start up and will replace the constant file variable, which we will be using for `api`calls.

**[App Initializer code with config.json file (for referrence)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-app-initializer-example-for-making-serviceurl-from-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts)**

Comment: Could you share your assets folder with config.json file, kindly release a demo. i think it would be helpful for me, thx @ Abhishek Kumar.

Comment: @pktechie i am unable to read the config.json file from assets folder in stackblitz, but i have implemented this approach in my projects, so try this solution locally on a dummy angular project to see this approach. `config.json` displayed in answer is only thing kept in `assets` folder.

Comment: currently where you are changing variable values, i mean in which folder back end or front end? if i change value from back end will it affects automatically, plz let me know.

Comment: @pktechie i am taking an empty variable in my front end file, and at angular app initalization i read a file from assest folder on the angular app, and replace that empty variable with value from file which i have read. And in every service, used this variable as base url for http requests. So, everything is happening on the front end

Comment: @ Abhishek Kumar yes i agree you and i got you, what you are explaining me. why i asked the above question is everything i did in the same way how you explained me but if i change url from assets folder it should affect to entire app automatically, but here its not and it will affect when i save config.json file after changing url. plz help me in this case i dont want to save file after changing variable value it should work automatically and thx for help.

Comment: @pktechie, okay, there is other way also using `environment.ts` but that too will require file save, Refer : https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/ , https://medium.com/@balramchavan/separating-production-and-development-http-urls-using-environment-ts-file-in-angular-4c2dd0c5a8b0

Comment: @pktechie so if you are not saving file, then from where you are going to change service url. Are you changing url from a UI screen ? - if yes, then from that screen you can get the value can update the `serviceURL` kept in the constant file, which is automatically used for all base url

Comment: see @ Abhishek Kumar  we are using .property file from java there we are changing url, if we change url there it should affect automatically here also, i am looking for that kind of scenario do you have any suggestion, even i tried environment file, but there also we have to save the file/compile the file. this url changing file should be common for both front end and back end.

Comment: @pktechie as trigger is happening from backend, so to update front-end, frontend must request backend on particular basis to know whether service url is updated or not (its called polling). OR you can see for server sent events.

Comment: @ Abhishek Kumar  can we change URL based error status code inside init() method of appservice.ts like .catch((err) =>{ if(some error status code== code){AppConstants.xhr.url.serviceUrl = this.config.serviceUrl;}})

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the "well known file" pattern. It's a path on a web server that exposes config information. The applications have to fetch the live config via a HTTP request while they are bootstrapping, and can refresh the config by re-fetching the data.

https://ma.ttias.be/well-known-directory-webservers-aka-rfc-5785/

It's based on an IETF RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785