# How to change one server URL to another server URL, if the server is down in angular6

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular6

I have 4 servers with different URLs, i want to change one server URL to another server URL if server is down in angular 6 application, if anyone knows please help me.

Consider i have 4 servers with different URLs(1st,2nd,3rd and 4th), here 1st server is having more priority and i want to make it has default. and my question is how to change 1st server URL to 2nd server URL as same as for 3rd and 4th also, if servers are down. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

service.ts file

```
firstserver ="http://111.121.1.342:8001/rest/formalities";
secondserver="http://111.121.1.342:8002/rest/formalities";
thirdserver="http://111.121.1.342:8003/rest/formalities";
fourthserver="http://111.121.1.342:8004/rest/formalities";

validateUserDetails(employeeDetails): Observable<any> {
    console.log(serversurl);
    return this._httpClint.post(serversurl(would be first/second/third/fourth server), employeeDetails);
}
```

here i have to check first server URL is up or down then apply to server URL which one is up.

Expected result:

I should be able to change one server URL to another server URL based on up and down condition.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a load balancer?

Comment: whatever it may be, plz help me if you know. I am eagerly waiting for solutions, I tried with app initializer but still unable to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't really know Angular 6 but there should be a `success` and `fail` method that is called when the response from the request is received. So you could repeat the request with a different URL if the first one fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for my above problem i got solution like in below, for that we have to take help from JAVASCRIPT.

step 1:->

create env.js file in the directory of index.html, like in below.

```
(function (window) {
    window.__env = window.__env || {};

    // API url
    window.__env.apiUrl = "http://RestWebService";

    // Whether or not to enable debug mode
    // Setting this to false will disable console output
    window.__env.enableDebug = true;
  }(this));
```

the  meaning of above env.js file is just we are creating one global variable called apiUrl, to store our server URL. So that we can access that variable globally. Next, we add a  element to the  section in our index.html to load env.js before Angular is loaded:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- Load environment variables -->
    <script src="env.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
    <!-- Angular code is loaded here -->
  </body>  

</html>
```

By default, JavaScript files such as env.js are not copied to the output directory when we build our application.

To make sure that the file is copied to the output directory when we run ng build or ng serve, we must add it to the assets section of our application's build configuration in angular.json:

angular.json file

```
{
  "projects": {
    "app-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/env.js"
            ]
          }
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              // ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

step 2:->

Create one service in the name of any, in my case i created it as env.service.ts in the directory of app.module.ts.
this is a service file will be used to take our server URL value, which is stored in apiUrl(env.js file).

env.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EnvService {

  // The values that are defined here are the default values that can
  // be overridden by env.js

  // API url
  public apiUrl = '';

  // Whether or not to enable debug mode
  public enableDebug = true;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

step 3:->

Create on service provider file in the same directory of env.service.ts.

env.service.provider.ts

```
import { EnvService } from './env.service';

export const EnvServiceFactory = () => {  
  // Create env
  const env = new EnvService();

  // Read environment variables from browser window
  const browserWindow = window || {};
  const browserWindowEnv = browserWindow['__env'] || {};

  // Assign environment variables from browser window to env
  // In the current implementation, properties from env.js overwrite defaults from the EnvService.
  // If needed, a deep merge can be performed here to merge properties instead of overwriting them.
  for (const key in browserWindowEnv) {
    if (browserWindowEnv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      env[key] = window['__env'][key];
    }
  }

  return env;
};

export const EnvServiceProvider = {  
  provide: EnvService,
  useFactory: EnvServiceFactory,
  deps: [],
};
```

EnvServiceProvider:->It is an angular provider recipe to register EnvServiceFactory with Angular dependency injection as the factory for instantiating EnvService.

EnvServiceFactory:->It's a factory that reads environment values from window.__env and instantiates an instance of the EnvService class.

So over all summary of this env.service.provider.ts file is, we export an EnvServiceFactory function that creates an instance of the EnvService class and copies all values from the window.__env object into the EnvService instance.

Finally to register EnvServiceProvider as a recipe with Angular's dependency injection system, we must list it as a provider in our application's providers array:

app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
import { EnvServiceProvider } from './env.service.provider';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ // ... ],
  providers: [EnvServiceProvider],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

We can now access our environment variables from anywhere in our application by injecting the EnvService, I am using it like in below.

service.ts file

```
import { EnvService } from '../env.service';

   constructor(private _httpClinet: HttpClient, private env: EnvService) {
    }

emplLoginCheckUrl = this.env.apiUrl+"/checkValidUser";

 validateUserDetails(employeeDetails): Observable<any> {
        console.log(this.emplLoginCheckUrl);
        return this._httpClinet.post(this.emplLoginCheckUrl, employeeDetails);
    }
```

tha's it for step 3.

step 4:->

finally what we have to do means before serving app, we have to build app with ng build --prod to get dist folder, which contains env.js file. from there we can change our URL's, if you change URL there it will automatically apply new changed URL in our application.

FOR MORE INFORMATION visit below site, thx Jurgen Van de Moere.

https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax and if request fails, retry with other server url:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: "**serverIP** ",

        data: , 
        success: function(){  
            alert("done");  
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Here retry post with different server id "); 
        }       
});
```

Comment: I am asking in angular 6 not in ajax, if you have any idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the request is getting failed and try making a request to another server but what if only the fourth server is working and you have to make three failed attempts all the time to reach the working one? Does not seem to be the most efficient way.

Instead, I would add an NGinx load balancer with health check:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

Comment: @ Nick Surmanidze can we use load balancer in development mode, there they explained while deploying. if you know how to use in development mode please help me because first we have try here without deployment if it works then deployment. thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you just need to install nginx system-wide. Then on your /etc/hosts (if you're on mac or linux) make an entry "127.0.0.1 yourdevdomain.test" and then configure nginx based on their docs as a load balancer. Then you make sure "yourdevdomain.test" resolves correctly and you would use it in your angular app as an API url. You can use weighed load balancing to give priorities to some urls over the others.

Comment: how abt windows OS, cant we use? because currently i am using windows OS, while deploying will use LINUX.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but you'll need to find a tutorial on how to install Nginx on windows + hosts file is somewhere else. I haven't worked with windows for like 5 years so I cannot guide you through it.

Comment: hi nick now i am trying to use load balancer, as i mentioned in service.ts file i have to fetch server url from load balancer and then i am using it inside my methods.my qtn is how to fetch servers url in service file from load balancer, if u have any idea plz help me. with demo would be very helpfull. thx